# Creating new branch in github but it isn't current?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, github, branch

I created a new branch in github for the 2nd part of my project. However, when I am on it, my xcode project reverts to an old version (not up do date with last branch)

clarification:

branch checkpoint-19

created new branch called checkpoint-20

when on checkpoint-20, the project I am working on is of a version before checkpoint-19

Does anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: most probably the branch is simply on an older state. on a related note, your workflow seems flawed to me

Comment: Thanks for the response-- do you know how I could clean it up and get my branch up to date? Also, I appreciate the feedback on my workflow-- could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you push your changes for checkpoint-19?

```
git push --set-upstream origin checkpoint-19; git checkout -b checkpoint-20;
```

Comment: Yes I did, and I tried that again to be sure. Still a very old version when on branch checkpoint-20

Comment: Have you done a **git log** on _checkpoint-20_?  Does it show you branching off checkpoint-19?

Comment: Thanks for that! git log indicates that its not branching off checkpoint-19, but checkpoint-18. Do you know why this would be or how I could fix this? I created a new branch like I always do and can't seem to think of what I could do differently.

Comment: Best thing to do is to delete your _checkpoint-20_ branch.  From there do a **git checkout checkpoint-19; git checkout -b checkpoint-20**.  You should now be branching off checkpoint-19 into checkpoint-20.

Comment: @malhotrag it's easier to branch with `git checkout -b checkpoint-20 checkpoint-19`, which works independently of which branch you're currently on

Comment: @Suraya when branching onto a new branch, by default the branch you are currently on will be taken as the basis. to change this you can explicitly specify a base (see above). You could also "fix" this by rebasing checkpoint-20 upon checkpoint-19...